# run a php script if dropdownlist value is changed

Tags: php, sql

Is it possible when the value of the dropdown list is changed to run the viewtb.php?

This is what I have atm but i still have to use the submit button to view the table.

```
<form method="POST">
<select id="selectcourse" name="selectcourse">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT crs_name FROM sp_crs");
while ($crs_name = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option>" . $crs_name['crs_name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="View Subjects">
</form>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name = "db_sp_dwcsj";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>


viewtb.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$sort = $_POST['selectcourse'];
$order = "SELECT sbj_name FROM sp_crs_ml where crs_name='$sort'";
$result = mysql_query($order);  
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo("
  <table border=1
  <tr>
  <td>
  $data[0]
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Load the table data via AJAX into a DIV element.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing concepts here. PHP scripts are meant to be executed on the server side, so "runtime" calls are not possible unless you execute a query to the server again using JavaScript (or others... like Flash). Most modern websites use AJAX, a very popular framework is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which would allow you to execute the query, as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).